# Когда вводное слово "видно" не обособляется?

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

Вот предложение: "Юлька пришла быстро, **видно** бежала, потому что запыхалась".

1) **Вроде бы не нужна запятая:** если верить ПАС, то вводное слово может относиться к одному из однородных членов (хотя таких практических примеров там нет).

http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=127#pp127 § 94. Вводные слова и сочетания слов, стоящие **на границе однородных членов или частей сложного предложения** и относящиеся к следующему за ними слову или предложению, не отделяются от него запятой (вторая запятая опускается с целью указания на отнесенность вводного слова к последующей части предложения): Лось шел скачками в сторону озер, должно быть спешил на водопой (Пауст.); Послышался резкий стук, должно быть сорвалась ставня (Ч.).

2) **У Розенталя** есть  сведения на эту тему есть, но тоже не  очень четкие.

3) А вот **в  реальных текстах** вводное слово **чаще обособляется**, например:

Лимончик внимательно к нему прислушался, посмотрел на него своим блестящим глазком, видно, **узнал**, раскрыл клювик, но снова раздумал и опять запрыгал как ни в чем не бывало.

А пёс тихо поскулил, **видно**, вспомнил чудесные лесные запахи, утреннее росистое серебро и помахал чёрным, недавно ещё драгоценным хвостом, будто согласился: прекрасное, волшебное было утро. [Виталий Коржиков. «Мурзилка», 2003]

Задумался, хлопнул напоследок себя по лбу, **видно**, вспомнил, что искал по карманам. [Виктор Мясников. (2000)]

Он опять внимательно все выслушал. Даже сел, **видно,** устал.[Андрей Кучаев.  2001]

**И вопросы:**

1) Правила ПАС действуют, в приведенных примерах вводное слово **не должно обособляться?** А если по контексту понятно, к чему относится вводное слово, то тоже не надо обособлять?

2) Не обособлять вводные слова, отнесенные к однородным членам,  следует (по формальным правилам) **всегда или надо учитывать структуру предложения?** Вводные слова могут дифференцировать однородные отношения, внося значения обусловленности, уступки и др., могут делить ряд на смысловые части,  а иногда однородный член интонационно выпадает из ряда (посмотрел, ***видно узнал***, раскрыл клювик...)